# Regex: check for the presence and absence of a certain sub-string

Tags: regex

I have three strings:

```
https://example.com/test/test/110x110.jpg
https://example.com/test/test/900x900.jpg
https://website.com/test/test/900x900.jpg
```

I want my regex to match only the second string. Specifically, I want the regex to match any string that matches `https://example.com/test/test/` but doesn't have the sequence `110x110` in it.

All solutions I found on SO refer to just excluding strings that contain a certain word, rather than checking for both the presence and the absence of a particular sub-string.

Comment: You could try using a negative lookahead `^https://example\.com/test/test/(?!.*110x110)\d+x\d+\.jpg$` https://regex101.com/r/tp8cis/2

Answer (score 0):

If 110x110 is always going to be in the same place then the following should do the trick:
`https:\/\/example\.com\/test\/test\/(?!110x110)`

https://regex101.com/r/bbUkVJ/1

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
(https:\/\/example\.com\/test\/test\/(?!110x110).*)
```

Matches the last part as well, and the whole thing goes into a capturing group.